# How do I stack 3 columns from single table to one column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to combine three combine columns  :

```
Population Estimate 2010    Population Estimate 2011    Population Estimate 2012
1,513,228                                 1,526,294     1,539,357
1,163                                      1,119         1,106
37,862                                    37,313          36,471
219,973                                   220,469        221,056
45,457                                    45,137         45,683
21,483                                    21,499         21,472
```

These are part of one table and I want to combine the data of 2010  then 2011 then 2012 columns into one  column. This data is being read from a csv file I have downloaded. Can someone please help me how to do this?

Comment: Since you want to _stack_ these values, it's a mystery why you have not looked at the `?stack` help page.

Comment: I tried stacking these but it is giving me an error message. Do I need to use melt?? I am very confused what to do.

Comment: Hard to know. You appear not to have a dataframe, since there are spaces in the column names but it's anyone guess what it really is since you didn't use dput to present it.

Comment: There's also the difficulty that `stack` won't work with factors, so you might need to use `stack(lapply(dfrm, as.character))`.

Comment: This is a csv file I downloaded and read. I did convert that into a data frame.The table you see is the raw table inputs I downloaded.

Comment: I have serious doubts that that is an accurate description. Why, you ask? Because `read.csv` would never leave spaces in column names.

Comment: Yes thats true. Each of the headings are Population.Estimate.2010 , Population.Estimate.2011 and Population.Estimate.2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your data that must be dealt with in addition to combining the columns.

First, you have commas in your numbers. R will interpret these as character *and import them as factors*. So we have to get rid of the commas and convert the result back to integer. Then we can "melt", e.g. reshape your data frame from wide format to long format.

```
# get rid of commas in numbers
df <- data.frame(sapply(df,gsub,pattern=",",replacement="",fixed=T))
# convert character to integer
df <- data.frame(sapply(df,function(x)as.integer(as.character(x))))
# rename columns with just the year
colnames(df) <- gsub("^.+\\.","",colnames(df))
library(reshape2)
# convert to long format
result <- melt(df,measure.vars=1:3, variable.name="year", value.name="population")
head(result)
#   year population
# 1 2010    1513228
# 2 2010       1163
# 3 2010      37862
# 4 2010     219973
# 5 2010      45457
# 6 2010      21483
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Very clear on what you need, but does this help?

```
myDF = data.frame("2010"=c(1,2,3,4,5),"2011"=c(6,7,8,9,10),"2012"=c(11,12,13,14,15))
reshape(myDF,direction = "long",varying = list(names(myDF)),timevar = "Year", times = 2010:2012,v.names = "PopEst")
```

The outputs are as follows:

```
> myDF
  X2010 X2011 X2012
1     1     6    11
2     2     7    12
3     3     8    13
4     4     9    14
5     5    10    15
> reshape(myDF,direction = "long",varying = list(names(myDF)),timevar = "Year", times = 2010:2012,v.names = "PopEst")
       Year PopEst id
1.2010 2010      1  1
2.2010 2010      2  2
3.2010 2010      3  3
4.2010 2010      4  4
5.2010 2010      5  5
1.2011 2011      6  1
2.2011 2011      7  2
3.2011 2011      8  3
4.2011 2011      9  4
5.2011 2011     10  5
1.2012 2012     11  1
2.2012 2012     12  2
3.2012 2012     13  3
4.2012 2012     14  4
5.2012 2012     15  5
```

Comment: Thanks Jack but somehow this is not working for me :( I saved my read.csv file in a data frame. Really dont know what is going wrong

Comment: if you could send across the csv, I can take a look at it for you.

Comment: Thanx a ton Jack. I shall send you the data over